# Como encontrar uma virgula dentro de um TextBox

Tags: c++, winforms

Eu tenho um Text Box no qual apenas pode conter uma vírgula, para tal, pensei em fazer com que o programa detecte, quando o utilizador usar a vírgula, se já existe uma nesse determinado Text Box.

Aqui está um exemplo do código que quero obter:

`if(*Verificar se já existe uma vírgula no textBox1) {
    //não fazer nada
}
else {
    this->textBox1->Text += ",";
}`

Comment: voce esta utilizando c++ ou winforms?

Comment: Poste algo que já desenvolveu, algum código, exemplos. Facilita a interpretação e possíveis respostas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei por usar o marshal, aqui está a resolução:

```
char* Valor = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox1->Text);
ContadorDeVirgulas = strchr(Valor, ',');
if(ContadorDeVirgulas > 0) {
}
else {
    this->textBox1->Text += ",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se **this->textBox1->Text** é uma std::string mas caso seja basta andar nela procurando por virgulas:

```
int contadorDeVirgulas = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) 
{
    if (str[i] == ",")
        contadorDeVirgulas++;
}
```

Depois basta perguntar

```
if(contadorDeVirgulas > 0) 
{
    //não fazer nada
}
else 
{
    this->textBox1->Text += ",";
}
```

caso você precise checar em varios lugares você pode usar esse for dentro de uma função ou lambda (dependendo do caso).